# How do I know security patch - 6788 applied or not?

Tags: magento-enterprise, security, patches, supee-6788

I'm new to applying Magento Security Patch. So here

Initially I have applied `PATCH_SUPEE-6482_EE_1.13.1.0_v2.sh` patch for which I'm getting `applied.patches.list` file in `app/etc/`.

And the `applied.patches.list` looks like now as below

```
2015-11-05 12:06:05 UTC | SUPEE-6482_EE_1.13.1.0 | EE_1.13.1.0 | v2 | 7e38036f94f250514fcc11d066a43c9bdb6a3723 | Tue Jul 28 14:29:35 2015 +0300 | v1.13.1.0..HEAD
        patching file app/code/core/Enterprise/PageCache/Model/Processor.php
        patching file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php
        patching file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Api/V2.php
        patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
        patching file app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/js/cookie.phtml
        patching file app/design/frontend/enterprise/default/template/giftregistry/search/form.phtml
```

1) Now I have downloaded and paste it on local magento root folder.

```
i.e., magento/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_EE_1.13.1.0_v1.sh
```

2) and I have created patch.php file written below coding.

```
<?php
print("patch");
print("<PRE>");
passthru("PATCH_SUPEE-6788_EE_1.13.1.0_v1.sh");
print("</PRE>");
?>
```

3) In my browser I have entered **http://192.168.0.52/magento/patch.php**

Automatically Command Prompt opened and some queries executed and eascape it.

But in `applied.patches.list` I am not getting `SUPEE-6788` Result as shown above result. So it is success or Failure I don't know how Can i find?

Could you please let me know how can I Know?

Comment: Go to app->etc if successfully applied it will created automatically applied.patches.list

Comment: when patches are applied a file named applied.patches.list is added in the app/etc/ directory

Comment: @Kothari, see updated my question.

Comment: @QaisarSatti, see updated my question.

Comment: @Kothari, If anything return error how can we find/get?

Comment: @QaisarSatti, If anything return error how can we find/get?

Comment: what error you got

Comment: try to upload all patches available in your version

Comment: @Kothari, how to know if any patch error? I think if patch not applied result will not print in `applied.patches.list` file right? So, how can i know what's error?

Comment: Once successfully applied then only this file created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31140/discussion-between-m-n-and-kothari).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments earlier: You can only be sure the patch was applied successfully if

1. the shellscript returns a success message and
2. there is an entry listing all the patched files in `app/etc/applied.patches.list`

If this is not the case, you can manually compare the changes applied via the patch which are included in the shellscript and check if they were applied.

Depending on the size of the patch (especially for SUPEE-6788) this will be a lot of work. But if you find out some files weren't patched you can be sure that it wasn't successful.

The best way to apply patches in the future is to set up a test-system where you have access to the files via shell and apply the shellscript. You should consider setting up an automatic workflow to update the files in your live-system.